# Have Xcode show breakpoint in Assistant editor if file is open

Tags: xcode, editor, breakpoints

So I just got into TDD and working with tests I started using the Assistant editor a lot more. I usually keep my test file on the left and production code on the right. However, when running a test, if I hit an exception or a breakpoint in my production code, the file opens up on the right again, even though it is already open on the left.

My goal is to have Xcode focus on the exception/breakpoint in the Assistant editor if the relevant file is open right now. Is there any way to achieve such behaviour?

The closest thing I found was in the Behaviour tab in preferences where I can choose which editor jumps to the exception/breakpoint, but this should depend on which file did it occur in. So if there is a problem in currently open test file, show it on the left. If it is in currently open production file, show it on the right. If it is in a file that is not showing, then show it wherever.

Thanks